# Running Stardew Valley from python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-10, steam

Currently I am trying to run Stardew Valley from python by doing this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['cmd', 'D:\SteamR\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Stardew Valley.exe'])
```

However, this fails and only opens a CMD window. I have a basic understanding of how to launch programs from python, but I do not understand how to specifically open a program that is located not only in a different location, but also on a different drive.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

This is on windows 10

Stardew Valley version is the beta and is located on the D:/ drive (windows is on C:/ of course)

Comment: Python2 or Python3?

Comment: python3 will edit tags @davedwards

Comment: I don't have access to a Python3 system at this moment to test, but this comment suggests use `subprocess.run` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python#comment63807915_89243 so in your case, remove the `'cmd'` parameter and pass only the path to the `.exe`

Comment: Can we have a `Stardew Valley` tag please?

Comment: Can we have more details on your os, Python version,  and just in case, Stardew Valley version?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon info is in tags and I edited in the rest

Comment: Thanks! I have a machine with all of those, so if nobody answered when I get home, I'll be able to inspect your problem

Comment: @RyanSchaefer, what happens when you manually launch the process from a command terminal? Remember to be in `C:\` and directly run the executable using the full path, see what happens. Also do you get a UAC dialog for admin rights?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you try using the steam commandline using the appid of the game:

```
subprocess.call(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe -applaunch 413150")
```

you can find the app id in the "web document tab" from the desktop shortcut properties
(which can be generated by right click and select create desktop shortcut in the steam library).
It will be something like this *steam://rungameid/413150*

Comment: `steam://run/413150`, at least on macOS

Comment: @AndrewMorozko This works on windows too, sort of: `subprocess.run("cmd /c start steam://run/413150")` or `subprocess.run("start steam://run/413150", shell=True)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `cmd`, you can start the `.exe` directly.

Additionally you should be aware that `\` is used to escape characters in Python strings, but should not be interpreted specially in Windows paths. Better use raw strings prefixed with `r` for Windows paths, which disable such escapes:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call([r'D:\SteamR\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Stardew Valley.exe'])
```

Comment: doing this says completed process with a code without actually running the program

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way:

```
import os
os.startfile("D:\SteamR\steamapps\common\Stardew Valley\Stardew Valley.exe")
```

What this piece of code does is, **it simply opens the file using its windows assigned default program**.

A disadvantage of this way of starting is that it won't return any process object. So in order to manage the process you need to use win32 packages or other.